# How to disable OpenMP support in graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

I want to disable OpenMP in `graph-tool`, but I can't find anything about OpenMP in `graph-tool`'s official documentation.

Is there any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. During compilation you can pass the option `--disable-openmp` to the `configure` script.

If you just want to disable openmp during runtime you can either:

1. Set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`
2. Call the graph-tool function `openmp_set_num_threads(1)`